# React Native not Navigating to Auth screen after login

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-native-navigation

I am working on authentication in react native app, when a user logs in, I save the token and then use the token to display the authenticated and unauthenticated screens. When I login, the tokens gets saved successfully but the app does not show the screens that needs authenticated unless I reload the app or refresh the token screen before it takes me to the screens that needs authentication.

So, I have tried to force update, by creating a function fetch token and including it with the Login function to know if the tokens saved in Async Storage will be shown but it did not work, I also consoled the token that i have in the router to see if it comes up at all after user logs in but the token does not even show at all till after I refresh or re open the app.

***authUtils.ts***

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getUserToken, getAdminToken } from "./localService";

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);
  const [adminToken, setAdminToken] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("fetch data triggeredssss")

      const token = await getAdminToken();
      if (token) {
        setAdminToken(token);
      } else {
        const userToken = await getUserToken();
        setUserToken(userToken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while fetching data:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return { isLoading, userToken, adminToken };
};
```

***localservice.ts:***

```
export const saveAdminToken = async (token: any) => {
  try {
    if (token) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("admin", token);
    } else {
      console.log("Error saving token: Invalid token");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error saving token:", e);
  }
};

export const saveUserToken = async (token: any) => {
  try {
    if (token) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("user", token);
    } else {
      console.log("Error saving token: Invalid token");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error saving token:", e);
  }
};

export const getAdminToken = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("admin");
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while retrieving admin token:", error);
    return null;
  }
};

export const getUserToken = async () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    if (token) {
      return token;
    }
    return null;
  }
};
```

***router.tsx:***

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Onboarding from "../screens/onboarding";
import AdminHomeStack from "./AdminHomeStack";
import UserHomeTabs from "./UserHomeTabs";
import UserSignup from "../screens/user/signup";
import UserLogin from "../screens/user/login";
import AdminSignup from "../screens/admin/signup";
import AdminLogin from "../screens/admin/login";
import { useAuth } from "../../services/authUtils";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Router = () => {
  const { isLoading, userToken, adminToken } = useAuth();
  if (isLoading) {
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }
  console.log(`admin ${adminToken}`);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {userToken ? (
        <UserStack />
      ) : adminToken ? (
        <AdminHomeStack />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} />
         
          <Stack.Screen name="AdminLogin" component={AdminLogin} />
          <Stack.Screen name="AdminSignup" component={AdminSignup} />

          <Stack.Screen name="UserSignup" component={UserSignup} />
          <Stack.Screen name="UserLogin" component={UserLogin} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const UserStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserHomeTabs} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

Comment: What is the "auth screen" you are trying to navigate to after authenticating? Where is a user authenticating in the code and the code trying to navigate or redirect to the "auth screen"? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of all relevant code you are working with and clarify what the specific issue is you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

lets try to wrap the `<Stack.Navigator>` in top of Stack, look like this:

```
return <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {authState != null ? (
            LoginedStack()
        ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name='LoginScreen'
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={{
                    presentation: 'fullScreenModal',
                    headerShown: false,
                    unmountInactiveRoutes: true
                }} />
        )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```